# What is the meaning of $\not{p}$ in physics?

Tags: notation, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I am reading [Srednicki's QFT book](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html) in physics. On page 286, the formula $(45.16)$ has a notation $\not{p}$. What is the meaning of $\not{p}$ in physics? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Feynman slash notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation), viz. $\not{v}=\gamma^\mu v_\mu$ for any four-vector $v_\mu$ (in this case four-momentum).

Comment: The notation looks dazzling.

Answer (score 3):

It's called the Feynman slash, and it's shorthand for $\gamma^\mu p_\mu $, where $\gamma^\mu $ are the [Dirac gamma matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices).